# Unknown terminal 'xterm-256color'

Tags: terminal, homebrew, unix

Keep getting a message in Terminal saying

```
tput: unknown terminal "xterm-256color"
```

This message typically appears when running `homebrew`, and while I can swear it's popped up on other places, I can't precisely remember. `echo $TERM` outputs `xterm-256color`. I'm not the best at diagnosing Terminal problems, so any help is greatly appreciated.

(I know this may be an issue when SSHing to remote servers that don't support xterm-256color, but in this case I'm just concerned about my actual system.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, answered my own question. [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804208/nano-error-error-opening-terminal-xterm-256color) had a post that I missed that described how the /usr/share/terminfo folder can get corrupted. Downloaded a replacement from that post, and the error message went away.

Comment: It would help if you could provide any information that might narrow down how this situation arose. Did you upgrade to Lion from Snow Leopard, for example? Did you install Xcode?

Comment: I had upgraded Lion from Snow Leopard and installed Xcode, but did so well before this problem started. I did uninstall MacPorts and install Homebrew instead - that's the one "unix-y" think I can imagine that may have triggered the issue.